# Laravel route with where clause not working as expected

Tags: laravel, laravel-5

I've got the following routes, which both work fine:

```
Route::get('/de', 'FrontpageController@index');

Route::get('/fr', 'FrontpageController@index');
```

The plan was to combine them into one statement, like described in this apparently working solution: https://stackoverflow.com/a/34404404/4688612

So the new code looks like this:

```
Route::get('/{url}', 'FrontpageController@index')->where('url', 'de|fr');
```

But, I get `This page isn’t working. example.test redirected you too many times.`

What am I not getting here?

The index method looks like this:

```
public function index(Request $request){

        $geoIpRecord = getGeoIpRecord();

        $nearest_places = getNearestPlaces( $geoIpRecord->location->latitude, $geoIpRecord->location->longitude );

        if($request->path() == 'de'){

            $page_title = 'Titel';

            $phone = constant('default_phone_de'); 

            return view('partials.main', compact('nearest_places', 'page_title', 'phone'));

        } elseif ($request->path() == 'fr') {

            $page_title = 'Titre';

            $phone = constant('default_phone_fr'); 

            return view('fr.partials.main', compact('nearest_places', 'page_title', 'phone'));
        }
    }
```

**Edit**:

In the meantime I found out that the localization package I am using is interfering somehow with the `/{url}` parameter.

When using the following code within my `web.php` the `/{url}` parameter stops working. It simply gets igonred.

```
Route::group(
[
    'prefix' => LaravelLocalization::setLocale(),
    'middleware' => [ 'localize', 'localeSessionRedirect', 'localizationRedirect', 'localeViewPath' ]
],
function()
{
    Route::get('/', function()
    {
        return redirect(LaravelLocalization::getCurrentLocale());
    });
});
```

I personally think this is a bug and therefore have contacted the developer of that localizaiton package.

Comment: could you show us index method in your FrontpageController. Also using languages as a route parameter is bad practise for multilingual website. Using a middlewarea more effective and easy to handle

Comment: @HasanTıngır: I added the index method to my question. I am still a noob when it comes to multilingual websites *and* Laravel. Thanks for your suggestion regarding the middleware.

Comment: Your code works fine for me.  What other routes do you have?  Remember the order of routes is important - when there are multiple routes that match the request, the first one that matches is the one that will be used.

Comment: @Don'tPanic: Many :) It is really weird. When I add a `dd('test')`*after* my route, it gets called. So in my case my route doesn't capture the URL when I enter `example.test/de`.

Comment: I just checked, and `dd()` *after* my matching route is also displayed - so a matching route does not stop parsing of your routes file.  Does the output of `php artisan route:list` look right?

Comment: Are you by any chance [caching routes](https://laravel.com/docs/5.6/controllers#route-caching)?

Comment: @Don'tPanic: Thanks for that artisan function. Yes it looks right. It yields the same result when I use the single language route commands, and when I use the combined one.

Comment: @Don'tPanic: No, I'm not using route caching. At least, I haven't enabled it.

Comment: Maybe some other route is conflicting. Just to test, try removing all routes, and just add a simple test: `Route::get('/{url}', function($url) {
    return $url;
})->where('url', 'fr|de');`

Comment: @Don'tPanic: I removed all other routes, and now it works. Thanks! That helps debugging further. I makes me wonder how other routes even can interfere when using the where clause, since it works just fine with the simple `Route::get('/de', 'FrontpageController@index');`command.

Comment: @Don'tPanic: Do you think this might be a bug?

Comment: It is probably something to do with the `{url}` being required in your current definition. If you visit `/`, it won't match.  Also note your `@index` method does not handle the case when `url` is not set, like at `/`.

Comment: `/` is handeled in a different route. (it redirects to /de or /fr, depending on the browser setting). I am using the https://github.com/mcamara/laravel-localization package. When I remove the routes that I use with the package suddenly my `where`clause works. So I guess it is a conflict with the package, maybe a bug. I'll ask the developer.

Comment: The error you are seeing is `redirected you too many times`, so you're looking for whatever does redirects - is the `/` route really working OK with these new language code routes?  Does the localisation package do redirects?

Comment: To me it looks like `{url}` is not being parsed, simply ignored, while using the localization package. I'll ask the developer of the package if this is intended.

Comment: Are you using the package middleware? `Moreover, this package includes a middleware object to redirect all "non-localized" routes to the corresponding "localized".`

Comment: Yes, I do use the package middleware. But it is configured inside a route group. All the routes that I tested and mentioned above are outside of that route group, so I think that middleware should not change the behaviour of my functions. But I might be mistaken (beause I'm still a noob...).

Answer (score 0):

If you are using https://github.com/mcamara/laravel-localization then I think you have to define your routes like this

All multi language supported routes should go inside this Route group

```
Route::group(['prefix' => LaravelLocalization::setLocale()], function()
{
    /** ADD ALL LOCALIZED ROUTES INSIDE THIS GROUP **/
    Route::get('/', function()
    {
        return View::make('hello');
    });

    Route::get('test',function(){
        return View::make('test');
    });
});
```

Here it match `example.com/de/`, `example.com/de/test`

And then define all non language supported routes outside this Route group

Comment: Thanks for the suggestion. I found out that even if I enter my URL like this `example.test/de` it won't get caputerd by the route at all.

Comment: Why did you add `/lang/`to the URL? Does it make a difference if I use `/lang/{locale}`or just `/{locale}`?

Comment: The regular expression makes sure `/hello` will not match.

Comment: @rkj: I agree with @Don't Panic. `/hello`would not match because of the regex.